# Load/Event Trigger Order in IE - Magento

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, magento, google-chrome, prototype

Afternoon all,

Right, bit of a complicated one to explain, Magento product page using a Colour Swatches plugin to change the configurable options to images, viewed in Chrome the link below works as it should do;

http://www.creare-scotty-3.co.uk/catalog/product/view/id/90/s/mens-t-shirt/category/237/?design=196&colour=94

What happens when this page loads is;

Magento autoselects the first configurable attribute (Size)
Based on the size, Magento reloads the colours drop down
Colour Swatches plugin hides the selects and creates the images (Prototype)
Colour is autoselected from code in URL (Jquery)
Selection of colour triggers the image to reload with the correct colour tshirt.

In IE, however, the colours don't refresh once the size has been selected, meaning the colour swatches do not load. To get round this problem I've triggered a click on the already selected size option.

This is at the limit of my understanding, can anyone else take a look and see whats going on?

Thanks,